# Can I install a Let'sEncrypt ssl certificate before I configure a virtual host?

Tags: ssl, letsencrypt, virtual-host

Assuming I am not close on which web server to use, Apache or Nginx but I still want to be over with the SSL certification procedure, can I install a Let'sEncrypt ssl certificate before I configure a virtual host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate before your webserver is up and running.

Let's Encrypt accepts two kinds of domain validation:

> - Provisioning a DNS record under example.com, or
> - Provisioning an HTTP resource under a well-known URI on http://example.com/

[(Source.)](https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/)

You can use the first challenge.  All you need to do is to edit your DNS to put a TXT record under your domain name.  The TXT record will need to contain the value of a token specified by Let's Encrypt.

[(Source.)](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/)